# How to set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com for Azure Active Directory B2C in React JS application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am developing react js application and will be using azure adb2c for security ([reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c)). To enable javascript in userflows, it seems I have to change redirect url to `b2clogin.com`. I have referred this `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin`, but not clear on this point:

> Set your Azure AD B2C application to use b2clogin.com for user flow references and token endpoints.

Can someone explain more on this? I have asked for any video reference in that page as well, waiting for their reply. I am not getting where to Change redirect URLs and where to Update in my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Question: I am not getting where to Change redirect URLs and where to Update in my B2C application?***

**Step: 1: Search B2C**

According to your case you have to your B2C tenant first. To do that, go to azure portal. Click on `All services`, in `search everything` box type B2C then click on B2C Icon as shown below picture. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Step: 2: Go To B2C Application**

Once you click on B2C icon you will be shown application on left tab menu, click on that and select your application you want to configure. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Step: 3: Select your Application**

Select your `application` from application list for configuration. See the image below:

[image]

**Step: 4: Configure Reply URL**

Soon you select the application you want to configure you will see the `Reply URL` below the page as specified on following screen shot.

[image]

Add or configure your `Reply URL` as you want. You can add many `Reply URL` as per your need.

***Question: Set your Azure AD B2C application to use b2clogin.com for user flow?***

To configure `b2clogin.com` domain on your `user flow` please follow the steps below:

**Step: 1: User flows (policies)**

Go to your B2C application domain you will see `User flows (policies)` menu under policies section. See the below screen shot:

[image]

**Step: 2: New User Flow / Existing From List**

If you have existing `user flow` you can pick from the list or you can create new user flow by selecting `New User Flow' on top. See the Picture below:

[image]

**Step: 3: Type A Flow Name**

Type a name for your flow as I have specified in screen shot. Have look on below:

[image]

**Step: 4: Page layouts For b2clogin.com User Flow**

Once the new flow created in your case `B2C_1_Test_Flow`. Click on that from the flow list. You will see `Page layouts` menu on left menu bar. Click on `Page layouts`. If you want to set `custom page url`  then click `Yes` to `Use custom page content` then `Custom page URI` would be enable for customization. See the Image below .

[image]

This is how you could customize your B2C `Reply URL` and `Custom Page URL`. If you have any more concern feel free to share here in comment. Happy coding!

Comment: 1) The system not allowing multiple domain url's to add for Reply URL to my application as i have added my app service application url as the reply url in b2capplication. 2) Custom Page URI - I have given as https://xxazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net/xxxblob/custom_login_ui.html , how can I add my custom html file to be under b2clogin.com as in your screenshot?

Comment: @VigneshwaranKS 1.Yes right you are, it does not allow to add multiple external url. 2. Though my UI is for Microsoft internal use, but you could customize your UI also please refer to this document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Comment: I don't want to use templates listed in user flows, if i customize my html for login and deploy to blob storage my javascript doesn't work as am not able to configure b2clogin.com in my app url. Any more ideas? I want to configure b2clogin.com as my domain.

Comment: @VigneshwaranKS Have you enable JavaScript settings on your B2C Tenant?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron when I click on run user flow - it redirects from <mytenantname>.b2clogin.com to login.microsoftonline.com. Could you please let me know if this behavior is expected?

Comment: Yes its expected behavior that means your flow has been integrated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, I have resolved my problem. Used the latest library of b2c from https://github.com/leszekczajka/msal-b2c-react and in the initalize method i gave my tenant guid id instead of tenant name and added ValidateAuthority as false like below:

```
authentication.initialize({
    instance: 'https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/', 
    tenant: 'xxxxxxxxx_tenantGUID__xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_signupsigninv2',
    resetPolicy: 'B2C_1_pwdresetv2',  
    applicationId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    scopes: ['https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/newsite/user_impersonation'],    
    validateAuthority: false,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!