# How to Set Redirect url using Azure AD B2C Sign in and Sign up userflows in android mobile application

Tags: android, azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**1)** We have created Azure AD B2C tenant

**2)** We have created App Registration

**3)** We had set the Authentications and created userflows (Signin and Signup) and Set the redirect url Web and Mobile Applications Section. See the below image,

**Redirect url in Azure AD B2C :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCTgg.png)

**4)** We have created the mobile application using React Native and We did the testing Expo Go App. See the below image,

**Testing our React Native mobile application in Expo Go App :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ8vu.png)

**5)** We published the mobile app in Google Play Store.

**6)** We installed our published app from the google play store in our android mobile.

**7)** We click and open published app in my mobile. To open azure b2c sign in page. When login to the app. not responding to redirect our Home page (Just Expo Go) app open and close it. And verify code we put it, and it will be not responding.

Please give me the suggestions for (How to Set up the redirect url in React Native mobile applications using Azure AD B2C userflows(Signin and Signup) ?

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check the configured redirect URI in Azure AD B2C react/native application created, i.e., public client application created. It should be **reverse DNS style**, i.e., **com.company.app**. For this, use the formula **“uniqueId://page”**. After the app user, i.e.,end user signs into Azure AD B2C native app, the app tells which page to redirect to in your application. Also, in the **‘TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml’** Azure AD B2C policy, the policy redirect URL should be stated as true as shown in below snapshot: -

[image: Policyredirecturi]

•   Once, the **‘UsePolicyInRedirectUri’** is stated as **‘True’** in the **‘TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml’** file, then you also need to add a redirect URI for each policy you use. For example: **https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy-name}/oauth2/authresp.** Thus, if you use, **‘Signuporsignin.xml’**, **‘PasswordReset.xml’**, etc. policies in Azure AD B2C for your application registered in it, then you will need to specify that many redirect URIs accordingly as above. Then, your redirection from after execution of one B2C policy user flow to another one will be smooth. Finally, please ensure that the redirect URI specified in the native/public client application created in Azure AD B2C is accessible and reachable and there is a **‘/’** at the end of that URI as it means that any pages following that URI can be accessed.

For more information, please refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile#metadata

[How to set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com for Azure Active Directory B2C in React JS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922170/how-to-set-redirect-urls-to-b2clogin-com-for-azure-active-directory-b2c-in-react)