# Set B2C change password redirect for Mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Team, i wanted to use redirect URL for change password B2C userflow for Mobile app, Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Only through [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview?wt.mc_id=b2ctutorial-blog-masoucou), user interaction with Azure AD B2C within the **Tenant** is possible.

> To change password for Mobile app, create a password reset policy by following below steps:

- Select your local account identity provider from ***Identity Providers*** dropdown.
- Go to ***Application claims*** blade and enter the information what you want to display when user resets password successfully.
- Enable MFA in ***Multifactor authentication*** blade to change the password.
- To [customize page UI](https://codemilltech.com/changing-the-look-and-feel-of-the-webviews-content-within-azure-ad-b2c/), you can set the [custom HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?wt.mc_id=b2ctutorial-blog-masoucou&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) for both the Forgot Password page and the Error page.

After creating reset password policy, make URL of the reset password policy as below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{YOUR-TENANT-NAME-HERE}/{YOUR-RESET-PASSWORD-POLICY-NAME-HERE}
```

To add this URL in redirect URI of your mobile application, please **refer** below links if helpful  :

[How to set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com for Azure Active Directory B2C in React JS application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922170/how-to-set-redirect-urls-to-b2clogin-com-for-azure-active-directory-b2c-in-react).

[Changing Passwords and User Info with Azure AD B2C (codemilltech.com)](https://codemilltech.com/changing-passwords-and-user-info-with-azure-ad-b2c/).